How to check if particular element inside child component with text is in the document or not from the parent component
This is my Login Component
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FaEnvelope, FaLock } from "react-icons/fa";
import FormInput from "../Components/Form/FormInput";
import { ChangeEvent, FormEvent, ReactNode, useState } from "react";

interface loginInputsTypes {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  placeholder: string;
  label: string;
  type: string;
  value: string;
  pattern: any;
  onChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  icon: ReactNode;
  onBlur: (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  focused: boolean;
  isValid: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;
  required: boolean;
}

interface fieldValueType {
  value: string;
  focused: boolean;
  isValid: boolean;
}

interface FormValues {
  email: fieldValueType;
  password: fieldValueType;
}

const Login = () => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState<FormValues>({
    email: {
      value: "",
      focused: false,
      isValid: false,
    },
    password: {
      value: "",
      focused: false,
      isValid: false,
    },
  });

  const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const fieldName = e.target.name;
    const fieldValue = e.target.value;
    const { pattern } = loginInputs.find(
      (input) => input.name === fieldName
    ) as loginInputsTypes;
    setFormValues((prevValues) => ({
      ...prevValues,
      [fieldName]: {
        ...prevValues[fieldName as keyof FormValues],
        value: fieldValue,
        isValid: new RegExp(pattern).test(fieldValue),
      },
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const emptyFields = loginInputs.filter(
      (input) => input.required && !input.value.trim()
    );
    const isFormValid = loginInputs.every((input) => input.isValid);
    if (emptyFields.length > 0) {
      const obj: FormValues = { ...formValues };
      for (let key in obj) {
        obj[key as keyof FormValues].focused = true;
      }
      setFormValues(obj);
      return;
    }
    if (!isFormValid) {
      return;
    }
    alert("Submitted");
  };

  const onBlur = (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name } = e.target;
    setFormValues((prevValues) => ({
      ...prevValues,
      [name]: {
        ...prevValues[name as keyof FormValues],
        focused: true,
      },
    }));
  };

  const loginInputs: loginInputsTypes[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "email",
      placeholder: "Enter your email address",
      label: "Email",
      type: "text",
      value: formValues.email.value,
      pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/,
      onChange: handleChange,
      icon: (
        <FaEnvelope className="absolute right-5 top-[50%] translate-y-[-50%] text-lg" />
      ),
      onBlur,
      focused: formValues.email.focused,
      isValid: formValues.email.isValid,
      errorMessage: "Email must be valid",
      required: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "password",
      placeholder: "Enter your password",
      label: "Password",
      type: "password",
      value: formValues.password.value,
      pattern: `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,30}$`,
      onChange: handleChange,
      onBlur,
      focused: formValues.password.focused,
      isValid: formValues.password.isValid,
      icon: (
        <FaLock className="absolute right-5 top-[50%] translate-y-[-50%] text-lg" />
      ),
      errorMessage:
        "Password must be between 8 and 30 characters and contain at least one digit, one letter, and one special character (!@#$%^&*).",
      required: true,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <section className="h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-slate-100">
      <div className="w-96 shadow-lg bg-white p-7">
        <div>
          <h3 className="font-bold text-xl mb-4">Sign in to your account</h3>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
              {loginInputs.map((input) => {
                return <FormInput key={input.id} {...input} />;
              })}
            </div>
            <div className="mt-1">
              <p className="text-gray-600 text-sm">
                Forgot your password?
                <span className="text-[#f7A200] font-semibold">
                  <Link to={"/"}> Reset Password</Link>
                </span>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="flex justify-between items-center mt-5">
              <div>
                <p className="text-gray-600 text-sm">
                  No Account?
                  <span className="text-[#f7A200] font-semibold">
                    <Link to={"/"}> create account</Link>
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>
              <button
                className={`font-semibold bg-[#FF9800] px-7 py-2 text-sm text-white`}
              >
                LOGIN
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Login;

And this is FormInput Component
import { ChangeEvent, FC, ReactNode } from "react";
interface formInputPropsType {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  placeholder: string;
  errorMessage: string;
  label: string;
  type: string;
  value: string;
  required?: boolean;
  pattern?: any;
  onChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  icon: ReactNode;
  focused: boolean;
  isValid: boolean;
}
const FormInput: FC<formInputPropsType> = ({
  label,
  id,
  icon,
  errorMessage,
  pattern,
  required,
  focused,
  isValid,
  ...inputProps
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
      <label className="font-semibold text-sm" htmlFor={id.toString()}>
        {label}
        <span className="text-red-500">*</span>
      </label>
      <div className="relative">
        <input
          id={id.toString()}
          aria-label={label}
          className={`border ${
            focused && !isValid ? "border-red-600" : "border-slate-400"
          } p-3 rounded-md w-full focus:outline-[#f7A200]`}
          {...inputProps}
          pattern={pattern}
          required={required}
        />
        {icon}
      </div>
      {focused && !isValid && <p className="text-red-500">{errorMessage}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormInput;

So whenever someone is providing wrong email or password then i want to check that error message should be visible inside FormInput
This is my login test file
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { describe, it } from "vitest";
import Login from "../../src/Pages/Login";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";

describe("Login", () => {
  const renderComponent = () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Login />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
  };
  it("should render heading", () => {
    renderComponent();
    const heading = screen.getByRole("heading");
    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(heading).toHaveTextContent(/sign in/i);
  });

  it("should render email, password input & login button", () => {
    renderComponent();
    expect;
    const emailField = screen.getByLabelText(/email/i);
    const passwordField = screen.getByLabelText(/password/i);
    const loginButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /login/i });
    expect(emailField).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(passwordField).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(loginButton).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("form should not submit if empty or invalid email provided", async () => {
    renderComponent();
    const emailField = screen.getByLabelText(/email/i);
    fireEvent.change(emailField, { target: { value: "invalid email" } });
    expect(emailField).toHaveValue("invalid email");

    //I want to check whether error message is visible or not in FormInput here
  });

  it("form should not submit if empty or invalid password provided", async () => {
    renderComponent();
    const emailField = screen.getByLabelText(/email/i);
    fireEvent.change(emailField, { target: { value: "invalid email" } });
    expect(emailField).toHaveValue("invalid email");

    //I want to check whether error message is visible or not in FormInput here
  });
});

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your assistance!
<div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
      <label className="font-semibold text-sm" htmlFor={id.toString()}>
        {label}
        <span className="text-red-500">*</span>
      </label>
      <div className="relative">
        <input
          id={id.toString()}
          aria-label={label}
          className={`border ${
            focused && !isValid ? "border-red-600" : "border-slate-400"
          } p-3 rounded-md w-full focus:outline-[#f7A200]`}
          {...inputProps}
          pattern={pattern}
          required={required}
        />
        {icon}
      </div>
      {focused && !isValid && <p className="text-red-500">{errorMessage}</p>}
    </div>

this is FormInput element which is rendered inside login file, so in login test case I want to make sure, that whenever invalid data is provided through input, error message in this component should be visible.
